# changing data of which country is shown based on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm basically pulling info from itunes rss feeds to show the top songs based on which country is selected from the select element.

I was trying to replace the value from the option selected and insert it into  the rss url to get that countrys top songs.The data pulls up fine however im
notable to  choose any other options. japan is the only one that shows unless i change which option is first. How do i get the options to change the data shown?

```js
// selects value for chosen country
var country;
//its selecting the value however its not refreshing. 
country = $("#country :selected").text();

$.get('https://itunes.apple.com/' + country + '/rss/topsongs/limit=3/xml', function(data) {
  var songArray = $(data).find('entry');
  songArray.each(function() {
    var title = $(this).find("title").text(); //grab song title
    var artist = $(this).find("im\\:artist, artist").text(); //grab                                                                          artist name
    var album = $(this).find("im\\:name,name").text(); //grab album name
    var image = $(this).find("im\\:image,image").eq(2).text(); //grab image link
    var audioLink = $(this).find("link").eq(1).attr("href"); //grab music file
    var audioDiv = $("source").attr("src", "audioLink"); //adds audio to source div
    audioLink = '"' + audioLink + '"'
      // youtube api to provide link to video based on the top                           songs populated
      // Set the search term
    var searchTerm = title;
    var link;
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=" + searchTerm + "&part=snippet&maxResults=1&key=AIzaSyBvccDrp39n-InLrjDvv4PH_vfNbN0J_iE";

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      var id = data.items[0].id.videoId;
      link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id;
      $("#song").append(
        " <br><br>Song :" + title + "<br> Artist :" + artist + " <br>album: " + album + "<br>" + "<img src=" + image + "> " + "<a href= " + link + ">" + link + "</a> <br>" + audioLink
      );
    });
  }, "xml");

});
```

```html
<select name="country" id="country">
  <!--  <option>select song</option> -->
  <option value="japan">jp</option>
  <option value="spain">es</option>
  <option value="france">fr</option>

</select>
<input type="button" id="button" value="get songs">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to watch for the [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event

```
$( "#country" ).change(function() {
  country= $("#country").val();
  $.get(....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get `value` or `text` of `selected` option

```
 var country;

//its selecting the value however its not refreshing. 

country= $("#country option:selected").text();
```

Or if you want `value` you can do this

```
country= $("#country").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use on change event

```
    <select name="country" id="country">
      <!--  <option>select song</option> -->
      <option value="japan">jp</option>
      <option value="spain">es</option>
      <option value="france">fr</option>

    </select>

    $('#country').on('change', function() {
      alert( this.value );
      $.get('https://itunes.apple.com/' + this.value + '/rss/topsongs/limit=3/xml'
    })
```